# Pass value to the sql of BulkDelete

Tags: dapper

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServerW3Schools()))
    {
        var sql = "Select * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID in @abc";
        var affectedRows = connection.Execute(sql, new { abc = 53 });
        connection.BulkDelete(connection.Query<Customer>(sql).ToList());
    }
```

The code above cannot work. Instead of directly passing the value inside the query  "**connection.BulkDelete(connection.Query("Select * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID in (53) ").ToList());**", is there any method to pass the flexible value to BulkDelete? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the affectedRows:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(FiddleHelper.GetConnectionStringSqlServerW3Schools()))
{
    var sql = "Select * FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID in @abc";
    var affectedRows = connection.Execute<Customer>(sql, new { abc = 53 });
    connection.BulkDelete(affectedRows.ToList());
}
```